# Remover horários do array se não satisfazer uma determinada quantidade de períodos necessários

Tags: php, array

Tenho um array com os horários disponíveis, sendo esses horários em um intervalo de 30 minutos:

```
$arrHoras = ["08:30", "09:00", "09:30", "10:00", "10:30", ... , "18:30", "19:00"];
```

Depois de alguns filtros que são horários reservados, tenho o seguinte array:

```
$arrHoras = array(
    2 => "09:00",
    3 => "09:30",
    6 => "11:00",
    7 => "11:30",
    10 => "13:00",
    11 => "13:30",
    12 => "14:00",
    13 => "14:30",
    16 => "16:00",
    17 => "16:30",
    21 => "18:30"
);
```

O que preciso é fazer mais um filtro removendo os horários que não satisfação a uma quantidade de períodos seguidos necessários. Todos eles atende a 1 que é ele mesmo, mas se for dois eu preciso dele e mais um horário seguido, sendo que não pode pular, por exemplo, das 9 para as 9:30 ok, mas das 9:30 para as 11 não, pois pula a sequencia.

Se eu precisar de 2 horários então o retorno seria esse:

```
$arrHoras = array(
    2 => "09:00",
    6 => "11:00",
    10 => "13:00",
    11 => "13:30",
    12 => "14:00",
    16 => "16:00"
);
```

Mas se eu precisar de 3 horários então o retorno seria esse:

```
$arrHoras = array(
    10 => "13:00",
    11 => "13:30"
);
```

E se eu precisar 4 ou mais horários irá me retornar um array vazio.

Comment: Uma pergunta, se esse *array* estivesse ordenado você iria querer que esse `$qtdeSlots` fosse o intervalo entre as chaves dos *array*'s?

Comment: Exemplo: em um *array* ordenado onde o `$qtdslots` for 2 a ordem das chaves era pra ser `0,2,4,6,8...`, se `$qtdslots` for 3 `0,3,6,9,12...` e assim em diante. É isso?

Comment: Então, não eh bem isso, cada slot meu eh de 30 minutos. Eu posso ver até pelas chaves a contagem pois inicialmente eu crio esse arras dinamicamente e tem todas as chaves na ordem mas com os filtros vai removendo as horas que não são necessários, só me falta remover pela qtde de slots.

Comment: Beleza, mas se cada slot seu é de 30 minutos, o elemento de chave 11 do *array* deveria na resposta, porque ele não obedece essa regra.

Comment: O que acontece, se `$qtdeSlots` for igual a 2, por exemplo, eu preciso de 2 slots de 30 minutos seguidos para poder aceitar. Tenho o das 9:00 e 9:30, sendo assim tenho 2 slots seguidos, sendo assim, o das 9:00 é aceito, dai tenho o das 9:30 e o das 11:00, não são dois seguidos, sendo assim, o das 9:30, não é aceito, e assim vou fazendo até o final. Espero ter sido um pouco mais claro

Comment: Ainda está confuso. Pode editar a pergunta ampliando o contexto, de repente até postando mais código de como você chega nesse array filtrado? De repente existe uma alternativa mais simples...

Comment: Você precisa de todos os intervalos em que o `$qtdeSlots` seja igual a 2(ou número q vc colocar) ou precisa que seja maior ou igual a 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução que consegui, até agora:

```
$arrHoras = array(
        2 => "09:00",
        3 => "09:30",
        6 => "11:00",
        7 => "11:30",
        10 => "13:00",
        11 => "13:30",
        12 => "14:00",
        13 => "14:30",
        16 => "16:00",
        17 => "16:30",
        21 => "18:30"
    );

$qtdeSlots = 2; // isso é variável 

$arrHorasOk = array();

for ($i=0, $c = count($arrHoras); $i < $c; $i++) {      
    $current = current($arrHoras);

    for($j = 1; $j < $qtdeSlots; $j++) $next = next($arrHoras);

    $slots = count(dateRange($current, $next, '30 minutes', 'H:i' ));
    if($slots == $qtdeSlots)
        $arrHorasOk[] = $current;

    for($k = 1; $k < $qtdeSlots-1; $k++) prev($arrHoras);

}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arrHorasOk);
echo "<pre>";



function dateRange($first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s' )
{
    $dates   = array();
    $current = strtotime($first);
    $last    = strtotime($last);

    while( $current <= $last ) {    
        $dates[] = date($format, $current);
        $current = strtotime($step, $current);
    }
    return $dates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para poder fazer o cálculo de quantos *slots* existem na diferença entre um horário e outro você pode usar os cálculos de hora

### Cálculo

```
$d1 = new DateTime("0000-00-00 09:00:00", new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
$d2 = new DateTime("0000-00-00 11:30:00", new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
echo ($d1->diff($d2)->i + $d1->diff($d2)->h * 60) / 30; // retornará 5 que é o valor referente ao slot atual
```

A partir daí você pode percorrer o seu *array* e implementar as regras que você precisa.
*obs: Use com php 5.4 ou superior.*